# RxAndroidBle waiting for client response

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I'm in the process of converting a pure Android BLE library to using RxAndroidBle and I'm hitting a bit of a snag.

The library currently opens the connection, reads a characteristic, and checks to see if it's encrypted. If it is, it goes on to read the next several characteristics. However, if it's not encrypted, it fires a callback to the client to tell them to pass in an encryption key (the client is responsible for either generating this key or fetching it from a server). Once the key has been passed in, the library writes this to the device, then carries on as with an encrypted device.

At the moment in RxAndroidBle I'm establishing the connection, reading the characterising, then closing the connection. Then if it's encrypted establish the connection again and read the other characteristics. If not, fire off the callback then establish the connection after the client replies.

```
public void connect() {
    connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(ENCRYPT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID))
            .subscribe(bytes -> {
                if(isEncrypted(bytes))
                    encryptedConnect();
                else
                    listener.onKeyNeeded();
            }, this::onError);
}

public void setKey(byte[] key) {
    unencryptedConnect();
}

private void encryptedConnect() {
    connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> Single.zip(
                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(A_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(B_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(C_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                    DataModel::new))
            .subscribe(this::processData, this::onError);
}

private void unencryptedConnect() {
    connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(ENCRYPT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                .flatMapSingle(bytes -> Single.zip(
                        rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(A_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                        rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(B_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                        rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(C_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                        DataModel::new))
            )
            .subscribe(this::processData, this::onError);
}
```

I'm completely new to RxJava but this approach, connecting and reconnecting, seems to miss the whole point of the reactive design. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of how to properly exploit Rx for this use-case. Namely, how to wait in one flow for a different observable to emit (client's reply to the callback), and how to change the route of the flow based on upstream results (change next action based on encryption state). Ideally, without changing the client-side code, as the library is already deployed in a few 3rd-party apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't see where you are closing any connections by disposing the `connectionDisposable`. The connection will persist until you either do this or the device disconnects.

What you want could perhaps be accomplished by saving your first connection in a variable of type `RxBleConnection`. Before the `.flatMapSingle()`, insert `.doOnNext( connection -> savedConnection = connection )`. Then use `savedConnection` for subsequent operations instead of establishing a new one.

And don't forget to dispose when done. Should probably also null `savedConnection` to avoid trying to use a dead connection.

Comment: To flesh this out a bit further: you could add a `.doOnError( throwable -> {} )` after `.doOnNext()` and, for example, test whether the error is an instance of `BleException` and do further analysis to determine exactly what went wrong.